# Why is a PDF 1.7 graphics imported by XeTeX from TeXLive 2015 not visible in a PDF viewer altough it was visible in the past?

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdf

I have been using XeLaTeX to make slides for my lectures since 2013. When recompiling my slides this year, I noted that some PDF images imported by `\includegraphics` macro become invisible. XeLaTeX just reserves an empty box of proper size although original PDF graphics files are visible in Adobe Reader and SumatraPDF. It was noted that this trouble occurs for PDF graphics of version 1.7. I solved the problem by exporting images (from CorelDraw) first to EPS format and then converting EPS graphics to PDF using `epstopdf` utility which produces PDF of version 1.4. However such a two-stage production of PDF graphics is not always a good idea. For example, EPS graphics exported from CoreLDraw does not keep opacity.

It is difficult for formulate a question in this situation. I would rather ask  TeXperts to investigate if my diagnose is correct and, if so, to restore a possiblity to import modern graphics formats.

Answer (score 5):

In TeX Live 2015, PDF images newer than version 1.5 are
rejected to include by default, that was unintentional, sorry.
The SVN sources were changed not to reject such newer images.
For a workaround until TeX Live 2016, please use, for example,
the following command to compile:

```
xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -q -E -V 7" filename.tex
```