# XeLaTex - Include PDF of version 1.6 or higher as picture

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdf, miktex

I want to include PDFs of version 1.6 (or higher) as pictures in my document. First I got the usual version-warnings, which I got rid of by changing dvipdfmx.cfg ('V 5' to 'V 6'). So now a PDF is created, but the pictures are not included (the area just stays white). A MWE will follow soon. Including the pictures as version 1.5 PDFs works just fine, but this leads to a too large output file.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269880/4918

Comment: I already tried that, doesn't change anything. Could the option interfere with some of the other options? Currently my command is "xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -q -E -V 7" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex".

Comment: Are you using texlive or miktex

Comment: Oh, miktex. Totally forgot to mention that.

Comment: It could be that in miktex the --output-driver doesn't work. But I can't test it now. Perhaps you can set the options through the cfg.

Comment: Thx, I'll have a look at that!

Comment: Which cfg do you mean?

Comment: The  cfg you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to answer. Do you mean setting the output-driver option via the cfg?