# PDF-1.6 appears with pdflatex but not with xelatex

Tags: xetex

Adobe Acrobat Pro extract pages from a PDF file and saves them as PDF-1.6 by default.

When those PDF-1.6 files are included in a beamer presentation and compiled with Xelatex, they don't appear (completely blank). But, when the engine is changed to Pdflatex, they appear as normal.

What could be the reason? What changes do I need to do so that PDF-1.6 are accepted by Xelatex?

Comment: Are you using TeX Live 2015? If so, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269880/42880.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but still getting the same behavior.